# How to skip downloading a dependency when a property flag is set in maven

Tags: xml, maven, pom.xml

I'm having some trouble articulating this question so I will try my best to abstract away as much irrelevant detail as possible. If more detail is required please ask.

I have a project containing a pom which contains a dependency which is always downloaded and unziped into a directory when a user does a `mvn clean install` on that pom. However I would like to forego the downloading and unpacking of that dependency when a user passes in a property such as `mvn clean install -Dcontent=false` but does everything else in that pom.

For a lack of a better way of saying this, I'd like to know how to make a certain dependency optional in maven? Not optional in the sense described here:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

but optional at build time as described above.

Edit:

**Build Step**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.company.random</groupId>
                                <artifactId>content</artifactId>
                                <version>${contentVersion}</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <outputDirectory>contentdir/target</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    <plugins>
</build>
```

@Mikita Currently this will always execute, how could I make this to execute only when `-Dcontent=true`

Comment: A dependency is either optional in the way as described in the link your gave or you need it...Can you make an example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using maven profiles. In example there is a `content` profile which will be actiated if property `content` will be set in `true`. And only in this case download `poi` dependecy otherwise don't.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>profile-question</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>War application with optional dependencies</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmespath-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.197</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>content</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>content</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Again poi will be downloaded only if you will use following command: `mvn clean install -Dcontent=true`. If you won't specify `content` parameter or set it in `false` will be donwloaded only `jmespath-java` from main dependency block.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I forgot to ask, I also have a step under build, which unpacks or unzips the content.zip file, if `-Dcontent=false` that build step still executes, how could I also make that occur only when `-Dcontent=true`?

Comment: Looks like it worked by just wrapping the `<build>` element with `<profile>`

Comment: @barthelonafan sure. Profile can wrap almost all elements... even `modules`. But idea stay the same... realisation depends on what exactly do you plan to solve.